# Overlapping image into another container

Tags: html, css

I am new to learning HTML/CSS, and I have come across a bug in my code.
As you can see in the image below, the shoe in the header is overlapping into the "Featured Products" container. I've tried using z-index, but I'm not 100% how they work and they dont seem to be working for me.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl6jp.png)

Any ideas as to why this is happening?
Thank you in advance,

Code:
https://hastebin.com/akelazivap.xml

Comment: Why don't you try making the "Featured Products" container's position: static;
I think it'll give your page a better look, and changing it's position to static should bring header image should come to front.

Comment: Don't forget to use *Developer Tools* in your browser. It will help you a lot with problem-solving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the first div's z-index to -1 and the second div's opacity to less than 1
(If you don't know what opacity is here is a link "https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp")

```css
.first{
background: red; 
height: 150px;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
top: 0;
}
.second{
margin-top: 150px;
background-color: green; 
z-index: 2;
opacity: 0.8;
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<section class="first">
<h1>HI</h1>
<img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/dog/dog_PNG50348.png" width="200">
</section>
<section class="second">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non sodales elit. Vivamus sodales, velit nec accumsan pellentesque, odio lorem blandit felis, eget facilisis quam lectus aliquet nulla. Pellentesque id fermentum lorem. Produi.</section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this is to use clip: rect. You can also change transparent collor to not transparent or set max height for shoe div.

Comment: Perhaps add some actual code to illustrate rather than just post a comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

you have an alpha channel on the background color. If you set it to 1 , then it will hide the shoe.

i.e.  .featured { background: rgba(255, 210, 150, 0.92);} change it to  .featured {background: rgba(255, 210, 150, 1);}

Comment: i.e.  .featured { background: rgba(255, 210, 150, 0.92);} change it to  .featured {background: rgba(255, 210, 150, 1);}

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I tried this and it didn't work

Comment: Perhaps add some actual code to illustrate rather than just post a comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the `padding: 7rem 0;` you applied to `section.featured` in CSS. It's better to apply `height` for your `section.featured` or define a new section called `section.inner-featured` in `section.featured` and put everything in it and then apply *padding-y* to the inner *section*.